есть ли ограничения на кол-во целей в Vuforia
могу ли я закинуть туда 20тыс целей? есть ли ограничения на бесплатном или платном тарифе? есть ли смысл изучать БД и как-то это реализовать ?


нет (5 это край для бесплатной  )

Дальше, бесплатная версия Vuforia позволяет разработчикам создавать приложения с ограниченным функционалом. В этой версии доступны следующие функции:

Создание до 5 приложений.
Использование до 100 уникальных пользователей в месяц.
Доступ к некоторым инструментам разработки, таким как Unity и Android Studio.
Поддержка до 5 целевых изображений для каждого приложения.
Возможность использования маркеров и изображений для создания AR-контента.


Платная версия Vuforia предоставляет больше возможностей и функций для разработчиков. Вот некоторые из них:

Создание неограниченного количества приложений.(может и 20 к)
Нет ограничений на количество уникальных пользователей в месяц.
Доступ ко всем инструментам разработки.
Поддержка неограниченного количества целевых изображений для каждого приложения.
Возможность использования более сложных технологий, таких как распознавание объектов и пространственное отслеживание.



Про последний вопрос не понял

Спасибо за ясный ответ!

На счёт последнего имел ввиду: стоит ли изучить SQL и как-то  брать данные с интернета только про конкретную цель пользователя. ведь было бы совсем не желательно сохранять на устройстве каждого пользователя данные обо всех 20тыс целях

Сомневаюсь что без маломальских знаний о базах данных можно таким заниматься(пригодится и в будщем)
